# meteor: cannot find module fibers/future while writing meteor method in typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, meteor, typescript, node-fibers

I am using meteor with angular2 using typescript es6 and i encountered this error while writing a meteor method for async function. I am facing a sync problem in the insert query because it is not supplying me with an error on insert when the name is the same. So i decided to use fibers and future but typescript keeps giving me an error that it cannot find the module for fibers/future.
I have tried 
**meteor npm install fiber,
meteor npm install future,
meteor add ostrio:neo4jdriver@1.0.2-fiber**
but nothing is working. If there is any solution for this please tell me. and if there is any other approach i can use to solve this problem please let me know.

```
import { Emails } from '../collections/emails.collection';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import Future from 'fibers/future';

Meteor.methods({
  loadEmailTemp: function(tempn: string){
    let temp = Emails.findOne({tempname: tempn});
    return temp;
  },
  getAllTemplates: function() {
    let temps = Emails.find({}).fetch();
    return temps;
  },
  newTemplate: function(tempn: string) {
    let err = false;

    let result = Emails.insert({
      tempname: tempn,
      subject: '',
      text: ''
    }, function(error, result){
      if(error){
        console.log("ERROR",error);
        err = true;
      }
      if(result) console.log("RESULT",result);
     });
     return result;
   }
});
```

My error is

```
W20161203-13:15:44.055(5.5)? (STDERR)        /Users/exMachina/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_1.1ulueqv++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20161203-13:15:44.056(5.5)? (STDERR)                       throw(ex);
W20161203-13:15:44.056(5.5)? (STDERR)                       ^
W20161203-13:15:44.057(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20161203-13:15:44.057(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
W20161203-13:15:44.058(5.5)? (STDERR)     at    Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
W20161203-13:15:44.058(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
W20161203-13:15:44.058(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
W20161203-13:15:44.059(5.5)? (STDERR)     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
W20161203-13:15:44.059(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/exMachina/.meteor/packages/ostrio_neo4jdriver/.1.0.2.1tve9ie++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/neo4j-fiber/lib/helpers.js:33:11)
W20161203-13:15:44.059(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/exMachina/.meteor/packages/ostrio_neo4jdriver/.1.0.2.1tve9ie++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/neo4j-fiber/lib/helpers.js:62:4)
W20161203-13:15:44.060(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
W20161203-13:15:44.060(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
W20161203-13:15:44.067(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
W20161203-13:15:44.067(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what wrong with your code, it looks good. So I am giving suggestions for other approaches:

- Using Promise: Meteor methods play nicely with Promise. So if you request to a REST api and want to wait for the results for further operations, Promise will be a great fit:

  ```
  import fetch from 'node-fetch';

  Meteor.methods({
    getFromApi() {
      retrun fetch('https://link.to/api-endpoint').then((result) => {
        // ...
        return result; // send result to client callback
      }).catch((error) => {
        // handle error
        throw error;
      });
    }
  });
  ```
- Meteor also provide a method to deal with async operation, it is [`Meteor.wrapAsync`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync):

  ```
  import fetch from 'node-fetch';

  const fetchSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(fetch);

  Meteor.methods({
    getFromApi() {
      const result = fetchSync('https://link.to/api-endpoint');
      // ... 
      return result;
    }
  });
  ```